# Xtify Framework and ASI-HTTP-Request Duplicate Symbols

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, xtify

Recently I created an app in which ASI-HTTP-Request and Urban Airship was used, it was successfully submitted to the Apple App Store, now our client wants to migrate to xtify, but as I follow the [steps](http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/iOS+Integration+Guide+for+APNS) to integrate Xtify in our app, I face duplicate symbol problem, where duplicate symbols are present in ASI-HTTP-Request and Xtify's xASIHTTPRequest, which is I think is included in Xtify framework.Here is the error screen shot. Please help me to resolve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xtify has an alternate build package which moves the libraries Xtify uses out of the compiled framework and into an ExternalLib folder. Check the SDK Notes on this page about the libraries Xtify is using and the link to the special SDK package for iOS:  http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/Download+the+Xtify+SDKs

Comment: Thanks Michael. I spent two hours today before stumbling here. Cheers!

Comment: you're welcome. xtify has to make that alternate build more prominent on the download page!